# Ladspa plugins for gstreamer on Windows

Tags: windows, audio, plugins, gstreamer, mingw-w64

For many reasons I had to go from Linux to Windows. So I'm trying to use gstreamer with some ladspa plugins. Does anyone know if it is possible to do so?

I tried to use this [plugin build for windows](https://github.com/kmatheussen/common-ladspa-plugins) and put the .dll files in the /usr/local/lib on MSYS2 or copy the ladspa plugins from the demo version of radium music editor. But anyway, gst-inspect does not recognize those plugins.

Any help is warmly welcomed!

Many thanks.

Comment: If you're still interested, there are a lots of ladspa plugins for Windows here: https://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/p/ladspa-for-win32.html. I tried a few and they seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you install GStreamer for Windows from the GStreamer download page, then it will look for plugins in these folders (from the documentation https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-windows.html):

- %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEFOLDER%/.gstreamer-1.0/plugins
- C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0
- [location of libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll]..\lib\gstreamer-1.0
- %GST_PLUGIN_PATH%

Perhaps you could set the GST_PLUGIN_PATH or GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tom,
While gstreamer did found libgstladspa.la as a gstreamer plugin (I think that your answer would probably be for this kind of problem), the ladspa plugins (tap, cmt ...) themselves were not found.

In the end, the solution was fairly simple and similar to your answer: I had to export the environment variable LADSPA_PATH to my ladspa_plugins folder.